# Unsure of -Wconversion behaviour

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

Given the following situation:

```
        char const a = (i == 0) ? 0 : copy[i - 1][j];
```

and

```
        char const a = (i == 0) ? '\0' : copy[i - 1][j];
```

Why does the first example produce the following: `warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]`, and yet the second does not.

FWIW, `copy` is a `char**`.

This behaviour is not limited to `char`, the same can be seen for other integer sizes, so it appears it is a matter of promotion.

Comment: Note that when i == 0, the value of copy[-1][j] is being assigned to a... possibly not what you want.

Comment: @LanceRichardson you are right, I meant it to say (i == 0) not (i != 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one result argument to `?:` is `0` (an `int`), the other result argument gets promoted to the same type — C++ requires that both possible results have the same type. Once the promotion is processed, the compiler discards the information about the original type, so at the time the warning is issued, the compiler no longer knows that what it's warning about had been a `char` all along. It doesn't complain about the second argument being demoted to `char` because it knows the literal `0` is a valid `char` value.

Comment: If this is the problem, that it promotes 0 to int (and hence the third argument), why does `char const a = (i == 0) ? 0 : 127;` not produce this warning.

Comment: It doesn't promote `0` to `int`. That value *already has* that type. Both values in your comment will fit in a `char`, and they're *literals*, so whatever their type, the compiler knows they'll fit in a `char`. Store one of those in an `int` variable and you should see the warning again.

Comment: So simply put, it is promoting my third argument `char` to an `int`, and hence giving me this warning. Despite the fact its counter-part second argument is a literal that easily fits inside `char`, and could therefore be of type `char`; and therefore not promote my third argument to `int`; causing the warning.

Sure. That's annoying, but fine.

Comment: Out of interest, why do the two types have to be the same? Surely the types should only be compatible with what they are being assigned to, ie `const a`, and not each other? Why promote at all?

Comment: The promotion isn't what's giving you the warning. The "demotion" assigning from `int` to `char` is where the warning comes from. If you were assigning to an `int`, all would be fine. You've written one assignment statement. When the two `?:` arguments have different types, the C++ language requires the smaller one be promoted to match the bigger one; signs are adjusted, too. There's no provision for analyzing the intended destination before choosing the type adjustments. Types are only promoted, which is one-way. The assignment comes later, and you get a non-required, vendor-chosen warning.

Comment: Before assigning, the right-hand argument needs to be evaluated. Evaluation yields a single value. A single value needs to have a single type. If you want multiple types, then write an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the type of '\0' is char, while the type of 0 is int.

The type of the result of the ternary operator when the second and third expressions have different arithmetic types is obtained by promotion to a common arithmetic type using the same rules that are used for types in arithmetic expressions. When one of the expressions has type "int" and the other has type "char", the type of the result is "int". The compiler is complaining that an "int" value is being assigned to a char variable.

A smarter compiler might keep track of the possible range of values for the result (which in this case is the same as the range of possible values for a "char"), and deduce that there is actually no possibility that the conversion from "int" to "char" will produce a change in value.

Comment: See my latest edit, it shows the problem is not with the 0... yet the array is of type char**, so it doesn't lie there either?

Comment: An int can hold every value of a char or short, but the reverse is not true, which is why you only get the warning when assigning a larger type to a smaller type.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that doesn't make sense, otherwise `char const a = 0` should produce a warning.

Comment: The key point here is that the value of copy[i - 1][j] is being converted to an int, and it is not a constant value. I.e. this is equivalent to "char const a = (int)copy[i - 1][j];" when the first expression is false.

Comment: *The type of the result of the ternary operator is the same as the type of the second expression*: I challenge that. As far as I know the type of an expression involving the ternary operator is a common type able of accomodating both sides of the `:` with no particular preference for any side. That is: `(i != 0) ? copy[i - 1][j] : 0` would yield the same warning.

Comment: @Matthieu: Thanks, you're correct, my first reference was chosen poorly. What actually happens when the second and third expressions have different arithmetic types is that a promotion to a common type is performed using the same rules as for arithmetic expressions. Will edit my answer to correct...